# See something far too seldom

Tags: meaning

From the Godfather movie:

Senator is speaking publicly in the celebration:

> This is a very very happy day for me and for my wife Mrs. Geary. We
>   see Nevada far too seldom.

I didn't understand the exact meaning of see something far too seldom. Does it mean thet they rarely get away from the city Nevada and take a rest?

Comment: Nevada is a state, a very large area (about the size of England), not a city, BTW.

Comment: @TRomano So? It means that they don't travel across Nevada too often?

Comment: The Senator is saying that he doesn't get much chance to visit Nevada, although he is, in fact, a senator from Nevada. The senator spends most of his time in Washington DC.

Comment: @TRomano So, see sth far means visiting something especially if you live in there, right?

Comment: "Far" modifies "too" which modifies "seldom".   "Far" there means "much".  He sees (visits) Nevada much too infrequently. BTW,  *see* can mean "to visit" but it can also mean literally "to perceive with the eyes." A person hoping to see shooting stars might say "I *see* shooting stars *far too seldom*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Seldom' means 'not often'. So 'too seldom' is the same as 'not often enough'. He's saying that he and his wife don't get to see Nevada as often as they'd like to.

Comment: You mean travelling across Nevada?

Comment: @D.B - It's ambigous. "We see Scotland far too seldom" could mean visits to Scotland, or driving across Scotland. The word _see_ in this context basically means _spend time in_.